# Imagefttext not showing text propery

Tags: php, gd, freetype, freetype2

I am using pjp gd free type library for one of php apps, `imagefttext` is used to put some text over images during runtime, it was working fine for quite a while now, but I made few changes recently after which it is not working correctly over most of the images but on few images it shows correctly, however all images are of same type(.gif).

but on rest its showing very disturbed text like this:
[image]

`code:`

```
$imageId = imagecreatefromgif($imageUrl);

        $angle = 0;
        $xCord = 4;
        $yCord = 40;
        $imageColor = imagecolorallocate($imageId, 222, 0, 84);
        $fontUrl = "./Verdana.ttf";
        $imageText = $firstName;
        $imageTextLnght = strlen($imageText);
        $fontSize = 25;
        $xCord = 4;
        imagefttext($imageId, $fontSize, $angle, $xCord, $yCord, $imageColor, $fontUrl, $imageText);
        $textImage = 'textImage.gif';
        imagegif($imageId, $textImage);
        imagedestroy($imageId);
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: can you show `$imageUrl` and did you tried with another image ?

Comment: `$imageUrl = "item/" . $itemId . "_". ".gif";` .. there are few specific images that are working fine, anf few specific the aren't.

Comment: i mean check the original images, if they looks ok

Comment: is there any transparency in the gif files you are working with?

Comment: no no transprncy, all is white background.

Comment: Add Link to `$imageUrl` and `textImage.gif` .. you are using .. like to resolve this error